# Oracle SQL: Simplifying my seemingly-horrendous subquery collection

Tags: sql, oracle, simplify

I have a rather large query being used to obtain a bunch of results, and I'm almost certain this is not the way to do it. It's filthy. It's abominable. First, let me explain my desired table structure:

```
+------------------+------+------+------+------+--------+
|   CURRENT_DATE   |  RO  |  FL  |  LM  |  AO  |  TOTAL |
+------------------+------+------+------+------+--------+
|    1/2/2012      |  31  |  33  |  70  |  10  |   144  |
+------------------+------+------+------+------+--------+
```

The above data set is collected from the following table:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|  CURRENT_DATE |  PORTABLE_PEANUTS  |
+---------------+--------------------+
|   1/2/2012    |         RO         |
+---------------+--------------------+
|   2/4/2013    |         FL         |
+---------------+--------------------+
|   3/6/2014    |         LM         |
+---------------+--------------------+
|   4/8/2015    |         AO         |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Essentially, I am trying to collect everything that's happening to `PORTABLE_PEANUTS` on a certain date, how often it's happening, and what exactly is happening within.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT total.CURRENT_DATE, results.RO, results.FL, results.LM, results.AO, total.TOTAL FROM 
(
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE, SUM(RO+FL+LM+AO) TOTAL FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.CURRENT_DATE, a.RO, b.FL, c.LM, d.AO FROM 
        (
            SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) RO FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'RO'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    ) a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) FL FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'FL'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) b ON a.CURRENT_DATE = b.CURRENT_DATE
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) LM FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'LM'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) c ON a.CURRENT_DATE = c.CURRENT_DATE
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) AO FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'AO'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) d ON a.CURRENT_DATE = d.CURRENT_DATE
) 
GROUP BY CURRENT_DATE
) total
JOIN
(
    SELECT a.CURRENT_DATE, a.RO, b.FL, c.LM, d.AO FROM 
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) RO FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'RO'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    ) a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) FL FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'FL'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) b ON a.CURRENT_DATE = b.CURRENT_DATE
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) LM FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'LM'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) c ON a.CURRENT_DATE = c.CURRENT_DATE
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') CURRENT_DATE, COUNT(PORTABLE_PEANUTS) AO FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE PORTABLE_PEANUTS LIKE 'AO'
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    
    ) d ON a.CURRENT_DATE = d.CURRENT_DATE
) results ON total.CURRENT_DATE = results.CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY CURRENT_DATE ASC;
```

Now this query works and, relatively speaking, it's quick enough, but it looks ugly. It looks difficult to maintain, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as CURRENT_DATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PORTABLE_PEANUTS = 'RO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PORTABLE_PEANUTS = 'FL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PORTABLE_PEANUTS = 'LM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PORTABLE_PEANUTS = 'AO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PORTABLE_PEANUTS IN ('RO', 'FL', 'LM', 'AO') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL           
FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

I'm not sure what else you want to do.  This might actually handle the entire query.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty awesome. Conditional aggregation - I'll have to remember that. Not only does it do exactly what I want in way less steps, but it does it a hundred times faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply use a pivot query - assuming you're on Oracle 11g or above, e.g:

```
with date_test as (select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual)
-- end of mimicking sample data
select to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') current_date,
       ro,
       fl,
       lm,
       ao,
       ro + fl + lm + ao total
from   date_test
pivot (count(portable_peanuts)
       for portable_peanuts in ('RO' as ro, 'FL' as fl, 'LM' as lm, 'AO' as ao))
order by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');

CURRENT_DATE         RO         FL         LM         AO      TOTAL
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2012-02-01            2          2          0          3          7
2012-02-02            2          1          3          2          8
```

---

Alternatively, if you're on 10g or before, then you can use the old-style way of doing a pivot, by using case statements and aggregating:

```
with date_test as (select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'RO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'FL' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'LM' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual union all
                   select to_date('02/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') session_date, 'AO' portable_peanuts from dual)
-- end of mimicking sample data
select   to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') current_date,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'RO' then 1 end) ro,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'FL' then 1 end) fl,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'LM' then 1 end) lm,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'AO' then 1 end) ao,
         count(*) total
from     date_test
where    portable_peanuts in ('RO', 'FL', 'LM', 'AO')
group by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
order by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');

CURRENT_DATE         RO         FL         LM         AO      TOTAL
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2012-02-01            2          2          0          3          7
2012-02-02            2          1          3          2          8
```

---

And, as requested, here are the above two queries without the sample data:

```
select to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') current_date,
       ro,
       fl,
       lm,
       ao,
       ro + fl + lm + ao total
from   date_test
pivot (count(portable_peanuts)
       for portable_peanuts in ('RO' as ro, 'FL' as fl, 'LM' as lm, 'AO' as ao))
order by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');


select   to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') current_date,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'RO' then 1 end) ro,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'FL' then 1 end) fl,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'LM' then 1 end) lm,
         count(case when portable_peanuts = 'AO' then 1 end) ao,
         count(*) total
from     date_test
where    portable_peanuts in ('RO', 'FL', 'LM', 'AO')
group by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
order by to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

---

N.B. from another of your questions, I see that you're going to be querying rows between two dates.

In which case, rather than converting the DATE column into a string, leave it as a date, but truncate it so that it's grouping at the day level.

I.e., instead of using `to_char(session_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`, just use `trunc(session_date)`.

That way, your where clause would then be either:

```
where session_date >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
and   session_date < to_date (p_end_date, p_date_format)
```

or

```
where trunc(session_date) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
and   trunc(session_date) < to_date (p_end_date, p_date_format)
```

depending on how you want to deal with the time parts of the session_date. The former will be able to use an index on the session_date column, whereas you'd need to create a function based index on `trunc(session_date)` if you wanted it to use an index.

Comment: Nice attempt, and I'm upvoting you because it's still a shorter, simplified version, but check out @Gordon Linoff's answer. That's precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: "nice attempt"? I've given you two methods, one of which is virtually the same as Gordon's (it uses count rather than sum), and one of which is the Oracle-provided way of doing things. I guess there's no pleasing some people! *{;-)

Comment: What, just because I added some sample data, so that you can run it for yourself as a self-contained test case? You do know you can just skip the top "with date_test as (...)" clause, right?

Comment: My apologies. Anyway, neither of your statements work. They both return `ORA-01722: invalid number.` Gordon's works perfectly. If you'd like to revise them, let me know and I'll check them again. Don't include the sample data.

Comment: when you say "they don't work", how are you running them? Are you running the entire query as I gave it (ie. including the WITH clause) or are you running it against your own database? Because they work for me (as you can see in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4334)). If you are running the queries directly against your table (ie. without the WITH clause), you neglected to mention the datatype of your session_data column, so I have assumed it's DATE. If it's actually a string, then you need to provide more information on the format etc.

Comment: I'm running it my table, not yours, and that column is indeed a date table.

Comment: and you say that both queries fail and yet Gordon's works?